# How to retrieve Customer ID on Create Order page

Tags: orders, customer, tax, admin-order-create

### FINAL EDIT (resolved)

A big thanks to Marius for answering this question. With his help and some information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574385/get-customers-shipping-address-country-in-magento), I was able to piece together a working solution. Here is the final (working) code block:

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
{
    $cust = $this->getCustomer();
    $custId = $cust->getId();
    $vat = $cust->getData('taxvat');

    $custAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($cust->default_shipping);
    $custState = $custAddress->getData('region');

    $customerLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
    $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
    } else if (strtoupper($custState) === 'FLORIDA' || strtoupper($customerLoggedIn) === 'FLORIDA') {
        if ($vat) {
            $amount = $price;
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }
    } else {
        $amount = 0;
    }

    if ($round) {
        return $this->round($amount);
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

## Original Question

As seen in [this question (self-answered)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71799/how-to-implement-tax-rules-based-on-presence-of-vat), I am trying to code a custom condition into my Tax setup.

This is working perfectly on the frontend and it **was** working on the backend earlier. I haven't changed the code, so I'm rather at a loss to why it isn't working now.

**How do I load the Customer ID when I am on the Create New Order page?**

The method I was using successfully is no longer working with my error log saying:

```
Undefined variable: customerId  in /app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php on line 658
```

Line 658:

```
$cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

This is within the `Tax/Model/Calculation.php` file, so it references this code block:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    if ($this->_customer === null) {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->_customer = $session->getCustomer();
        } elseif ($session->getCustomerId()) {
            $this->_customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($session->getCustomerId());
        } else {
            $this->_customer = false;
        }
    }
    return $this->_customer;
}
```

The method I am modifying is `calcTaxAmount`:

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax = false, $round = true)
{
    $cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
    $vat = $cust->getData('taxvat');

    $customerLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getRegion();
    $taxRate = $taxRate / 100;

    if ($priceIncludeTax) {
        $amount = $price * (1 - 1 / (1 + $taxRate));
    } else if (strtoupper($customerLoggedIn) === 'FLORIDA') {
        if ($vat) {
            $amount = $price;
        } else {
            $amount = $price * $taxRate;
        }
    } else {
        $amount = 0;
    }

    if ($round) {
        return $this->round($amount);
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

Comment: you just need the customer id when create new order right?

Comment: Well, I need the customer ID in order to retrieve the Shipping Address's State. I just need to see if it is being shipped to Florida.

Comment: check the customer registry if any when create order

Comment: How would I go about that programmatically?

Comment: can you post the lines above `658`?

Comment: Line 658 is the beginning of my `calcTaxAmount` method, within a local copy of the `Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` file, so there is a lot of code in the file, but it's all default other than this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
$cust = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
```

Try using this:

```
$cust = $this->getCustomer();
```

but be careful. `$cust` may be `null` in some cases.

On a side note, this does not look good:

```
$custAdmin = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$custAdminId = $custAdmin->getId();
$region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($custAdminId);
$stateCode = $region->getCode();
$stateName = $region->getName();
```

you are basically getting the customer id from the session then, loading the region with the same id as the customer.
I'm sure this is not what you want to do.

Comment: It looks like we're in business now. And yes, the code block you quoted there is terrible and it's actually not doing anything (this variables are processed, but never used) so I deleted it. I'm going to update my question to be a little more concise for future visitors. Thanks for your help!